# "Unable to locate element" exception with WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting an "Unable to locate element" exception while running the below code. My expected output is `First Page of GoogleResults`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver;
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement oSearchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    oSearchField.sendKeys("Selenium");

    WebElement oButton = driver.findElement(By.name("btnG"));
    oButton.click();

    //String oNext = "//td[@class='b navend']/a[@id='pnnext']";
    WebElement oPrevious;
    oPrevious = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='b navend']/a[@id='pnprev']"));

    if (!oPrevious.isDisplayed()){
        System.out.println("First Page of GoogleResults");
    }
}
```

If I run the above code I get "Unable to Locate Element Exception". I know the Previous Button Element is not in the first page of the Google Search Results page, but I want to suppress the exception and get the output of the next step `if` condition.

Comment: After retaging even if I keep java as last option why is it coming in as first. And the page title gets messed up because of that. Can be misleading. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Logical mistake -

```
oPrevious = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='b navend']/a[@id='pnprev']"));
```

will fail or give error if WebDriver can't locate the element.

Try using something like -

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can pass the xpath to the function like

```
boolean x = isElementPresent(By.xpath("//td[@class='b navend']/a[@id='pnprev']"));
if (!x){
    System.out.println("First Page of GoogleResults");
}
```

Comment: Good stuff, remember in the imports to  import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException rather than java.util.NoSuchElementException (as my IDE did initially).